# drawViewHierarchyInRect causing VM CG Image memory leak

Tags: objective-c, ipad, memory-leaks

I have a function that takes a screenshot of the interface and saves it to an instance property (called self.interfaceScreenshot).

```
-(void)takeInterfaceScreenshot{
   // Iterate over every window from back to front

   for (UIWindow *window in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows])
   {
       if (![window respondsToSelector:@selector(screen)] || [window screen] == [UIScreen mainScreen])
       {
           UIGraphicsBeginImageContext([window bounds].size);
           [[self view] drawViewHierarchyInRect:[window bounds] afterScreenUpdates:YES];
      }
  }

  UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

  if(self.interfaceScreenshot != nil){
      self.interfaceScreenshot = nil;
  }

  self.interfaceScreenshot = image;
}
```

But i am seeing in the Instruments profiler that every time i call this function, there is an  extra persistent instance that leaks in the VM : CG Image section of the allocation statistics:

[image]

I am using iOS7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial an error i figured out that the error was to have `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext([window bounds].size);` inside the loop. This works just fine:

```
-(void)takeInterfaceScreenshot{

  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext([window bounds].size);

  // Iterate over every window from back to front
  for (UIWindow *window in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows])
  {
      if (![window respondsToSelector:@selector(screen)] || [window screen] == [UIScreen mainScreen])
      {
         [[self view] drawViewHierarchyInRect:[window bounds] afterScreenUpdates:YES];
      }
   }

   UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
   UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

   if(self.interfaceScreenshot != nil){
       self.interfaceScreenshot = nil;
   }

   self.interfaceScreenshot = image;
}
```